# How to correctly position a graphics included in an anchored TikZ node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment

In this MWE, `\myfig` seems to be shifted horizontally by some half `\pgflinewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\myfig{\includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4-numbered}}
% just fooling around:

\begin{document}

Reference:\\
\myfig

This works:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0] { \myfig };
\end{tikzpicture}

Overfull hbox (about 0.4pt too wide):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] { \myfig };
\end{tikzpicture}

Overfull hbox (about 0.2pt too wide):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west, outer xsep=0] { \myfig };
\end{tikzpicture}

Overfull hbox (about 2pt too wide):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{10\pgflinewidth}
    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west, outer xsep=0] { \myfig };
\end{tikzpicture}

Workaround:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{100\pgflinewidth}
    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west, outer xsep=-\pgflinewidth/2] { \myfig };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a better workaround than what I am using?

Comment: Interestingly there is no overfull if I use `\node[...] at (0,0) ...` instead of `\draw (0,0) node ... `

Comment: Use `\path (0,0) node[...] { \myfig };` instead of `\draw...`.